# Is it true that $(\ \forall S \ \ \ \ \int_{S} A dS = 0 )\implies A \equiv 0 $

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it true that

$(\  \forall S \ \ \ \  \int_{S} A dS = 0 )\implies A \equiv 0 $

where $S$ is a surface and $A$ is some function which takes values on $S$?

Is there a requirement on the smoothness of $S$? (In my case it is the boundary of a region in which some function $u$ satisfies Laplace's equation.)

Does this result generalise to

$( \forall R \ \ \int_{R} A dR = 0) \implies A \equiv 0 $?

For $R$ $\subset \mathbb{R}^n$  with $dim(R) = k$ - some specified type of region where the integral is defined, e.g. a surface, a volume, etc.?

I have a feeling that the first is true, but I can't manage to prove it.

---

Given the counterexample in the answers, let's impose the restriction that A, R are continuous.

Comment: Do you at least have that $A$ is continuous?

Comment: Erm. Well, in my problem, yes, but I am interested in how this works in the general case, so if there is an answer which is restricted to $A \in C^{n}[R]$ or $A \in C^{\infty}[R]$ then I would very much like to know. @Cocopuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ross B. has demonstrated a counterexample if $A$ is discontinuous.

Suppose $A \ne 0$ is continuous, and let $A(x_0) > 0$ WLOG. By continuity, there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ on which $A>0;$ form a surface $S'$ from this neighborhood.

Then $\int_{S'} A dS' > \int_{S'} \min(A) dS' = \min(A)\text{vol}(S') > 0,$ a contradiction. Thus $A = 0.$

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is not continuous, for your second answer a counterexample would be the function which is $1$ at $x=0$ and $0$ everywhere else.